# getting length of mp3 file

Tags: php, audio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get the length of an audio file php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069574/get-the-length-of-an-audio-file-php)

i am using php for my project.i have to build some system where i need to get length of mp3 file.

how i can get length of mp3 file ?
i got suggetion from my previousquestion.
accept
You won't be able to do audio processing correctly with PHP alone, you should take a look at the following:

http://sox.sourceforge.net/

http://ffmpeg.org/

http://lame.sourceforge.net/

Comment: do you mean the size of the file, or the length in time of the sound?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may use the [getID3](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/) library to read the file's metadata. There is a attribute called `playtime_length` (also see [this code example](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/source/structure.txt)) that you can read and convert to a floating point number using the php `floatval()` function.