# save audio file length in db

Tags: php, mysql, audio

I have almost 200 ogg files, and I need to get their audio length and to save it in a database.

I know PHP but I assume that I'll not be able to do my task with PHP and MySQL.

Can you recommend a solution for my problem?

Comment: [Ogg.class.php](http://opensource.grisambre.net/ogg/) Read the doc, which has some info about getting the duration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using linux / unix and have ffmpeg installed, just do this:

```
$time = exec("ffmpeg -i " . escapeshellarg($path) . " 2>&1 | grep 'Duration' | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,//");
list($hms, $milli) = explode('.', $time);
list($hours, $minutes, $seconds) = explode(':', $hms);
$total_seconds = ($hours * 3600) + ($minutes * 60) + $seconds;
```

If not then you should take a look at some library that support this feature, maybe something like [`this`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.audio.php) or [`ogg`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.audio.php) like Kacey mentioned.

So you can use something like

```
KTaglib_MPEG_AudioProperties::getLength
```

The code in the beginning of my answer is originally written by Stephen J. Fuhry and can be seen [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069574/get-the-length-of-an-audio-file-php)