# Get media file duration (Server-side)

Tags: php

I'm looking for a way to get an accurate duration of media files. I've researched many solutions online including the getID3 library but ID3 tags are too easily edited or may not be populated in certain cases. I'm on a shared host at the moment so the ffmpeg library isn't an option either as I can't install anything on this host (GoDaddy).

I'm primarily looking at MP3, WMV, WAV, MP4, MPEG, AVI, and MOV files at the moment. Is there a way to get their duration using, preferably, PHP? I'd be happy with any solution that works though.

Will truly appreciate help.

Thanks

Comment: getID3 is likely the only way to go, unless you want to start parsing the files themselves. Which is not impossible but likely to be a lot of work.

Comment: @Mr. Smith, thanks for the edit.

Comment: @Pekka, thanks but ID3 tags are easily edited which is why I'm skeptical about using them. I'd like a more accurate way of measuring the duration - something that's not easily faked.

Comment: There's a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069574/get-the-length-of-an-audio-file-php

Comment: @G33KCO thanks but the solutions on that page are either geared towards MP3 or require installation of libraries, both of which don't match what I mentioned in my question as criteria that a solution must meet to be usable for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one looks like it supports multiple media formats.

http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/428301/getting-video-duration-without-ffmpeg

```
    function getDuration($file){
        if (file_exists($file)){
            ## open and read video file
            $handle = fopen($file, "r");

            ## read video file size
            $contents = fread($handle, filesize($file));
            fclose($handle);
            $make_hexa = hexdec(bin2hex(substr($contents,strlen($contents)-3)));
            if (strlen($contents) > $make_hexa){
                $pre_duration = hexdec(bin2hex(substr($contents,strlen($contents)-$make_hexa,3))) ;
                $post_duration = $pre_duration/1000;
                $timehours = $post_duration/3600;
                $timeminutes =($post_duration % 3600)/60;
                $timeseconds = ($post_duration % 3600) % 60;
                $timehours = explode(".", $timehours);
                $timeminutes = explode(".", $timeminutes);
                $timeseconds = explode(".", $timeseconds);
                $duration = $timehours[0]. ":" . $timeminutes[0]. ":" . $timeseconds[0];}
                return $duration;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

In order to use it just do the following:

```
## first, define video file and location
$video_file = "somedirectory/video.flv";
## call out the function
echo getDuration($video_file);
```

I copped that from the link above. I tried it on a couple of media types that you mentioned and it seemed to work fine.

Comment: Glad I could help! I plan to use this for a few of my own projects as well.